# What is my telegram bot shutdown in night time?

Tags: bots

I start my bot telegram weather bot (41 lines code) in 23.05.23 but day (24.05.23) my bot dosent working! Bot is shut down! This is restart server? but i open console for dleate other console (Other consol dosent working) and close console.

I dont modify code and console!